# How to count the total number of selected checkboxes in an HTML table

Tags: javascript, php, html

How can i count the number of the selected checkboxes from this table:

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <center>
                <form>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $rws['amount']; ?>" />
                </form>
            </center>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: either there is only one or you have invalid html markup. A form cannot start in a tablecell and end in a different one - not that the form above is even closed.

Comment: Using jquery it is easy to make: `$('table').find(':checkbox').length`

Answer (score 2):

`querySelectorAll` lets you get a list of elements matching any CSS selector, so you can use that to get the checkboxes. You can use `Array.prototype.reduce` on it in order to count the number of them that are checked. So:

```
var count = Array.prototype.reduce.call(
    document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]"),
    function(sum, cb) {
        return sum + cb.checked ? 1 : 0;
    },
    0
);
```

The "array-like" part of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript/9329476#9329476) explains that use of `Array.prototype.reduce` that lets us treat the list from `querySelectorAll` as though it were an array when it isn't.

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) has a description of how `reduce` works.

Comment: how can i add the total amount of all selected chect boxes